# How can I count occurrences of a string in a csv file row if another row has a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, dataframe

I have a csv file with one row of country values and one row of Olympic medals. iI want to count which country got how many medals.

I tried it with pandas but it gives me the error message that it cannot find the row "country", although the row does exist and it is named country
The CSV file:

[image: screenshot of CSV file contents]

```py
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('olympics.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:

    df = pd.read_csv("olympics.csv",
                     index_col=["NOC","Medal"])
                     #usecols=["NOC","Medal"])
    #df.sort_index()

    #grouped = df.groupby(['NOC', 'Medal'])

    grouped = df.groupby(['NOC','Medal'])['NOC'].count()

print(grouped)
```

The output should be like:

```
USA 2366 
UK  2189 
Denmark 1455 
....
```

Comment: I can also solve the problem without the use of pandas, i already tried it with dict reader but that didn't word as well

Comment: "country" or "NOC"?

Comment: So your csv looks like this right ->
(row 1 -> usa, uk, denmark) |
(row 2 -> 2366, 2189, 1455) ?

Comment: Sorry it is named NOC I just wrote country for the understanding

Comment: there is one row for the name of the country which is called NOC and there is one row for the name of the medal which is called medal and ther is only gold or silver or bronze written in it,

Comment: So there is one occurence of each country for each medal they got and I want to count all the medals together for each country --- is that understandable?

Comment: I guess there is confusion on how your csv looks like, can you please edit the question and put a sample CSV !!

Comment: I added a sample of the csv file, I need only the rows NOC and Medal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved using DictReader from "csv" library.

```
import csv
import collections

csv_file = open('olympics.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
csv_input = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
country_medals_map = collections.defaultdict(int)
# initializes the country_medals_map with default value as int which will be 0.
# e.g test_dict = defaultdict(int), print(test_dict['not_set_key']) => 0

for input in csv_input:
    country_medals_map[input['NOC']] += 1 if input['Medal'] in ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'] else 0
    # set dict key as the rows country('NOC') value and increasing the dict value if medal present in GOLD SILVER or BRONZE.

 # finally printing our dict formed.
 for key, value in country_medals_map.items():
     print(key, '-', value)

 # output
 # GRE - 10
 # AUS - 5
 # Uk - 20
```

If you want the output to be sorted, instead of sorting(updating) it while creating, sort it afterward.

```
sorted_by_medals = sorted(country_medals_map.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)

# printing our sorted output
for item in sorted_by_medals:
     print(item)

# output
# ('Uk', 20)
# ('GRE', 10)
# ('AUS', 5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i tried the code but unfortunately I get an error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3782: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: ohh, this is due to how the file is opened will update the answer it requires "open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')" this, this will solve the problem

Comment: Now it works, there was the encoding missing, because there are some German characters in the file. Thank you!!!! You helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer without the use of pandas myself.

````````
import csv

d = {}

with open('olympics.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:

    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
    #print(dialect)

    # Move to beginning of file
    f.seek(0)

    # DictReader uses the first row in the file as headers.
    r = csv.DictReader(f, dialect=dialect)

    for row in r:

        if row['Medal'] == 'Gold'or 'Silver'or 'Bronze':
            d[row['NOC']] = d.get(row['NOC'], 0) + 1
            #d.sort(key=itemgetter(1)
for k in d:
    #k.sort(key=lambda element: element[1]

    print('{}  {}'.format(k, d[k]))```````
````````

Comment: I am just wondering how to sort it because the things that I tried, the two that are commented out, did not work

Comment: I have explained the sorting in my answers last part, you can refer to that.